# How to build/extract specific JAR files from Android source code?

Tags: android, jar, android-source, bootclasspath

I would like to build/extract specific JAR files from Android source code. My understanding is that JAR files for Android framework are specified using `BOOTCLASSPATH`, that for KitKat version are specified in [core_base.mk file](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/build/target/product/core_base.mk#71).

The specific jar files are:

```
PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS := core:conscrypt:okhttp:core-junit:bouncycastle:ext:framework:framework2:telephony-common:voip-common:mms-common:android.policy:services:apache-xml:webviewchromium
```

Since Android-SDK provided `android.jar` file does not contain source code and all the APIs (e.g., it does not include methods which have `@hide` attribute attached), I was thinking to build an `android.jar` file based on these `BOOTCLASSPATH` specified JAR files.

Can someone please guide me how can I achieve this? In my case, I only need these JAR files, not all the `.java` classes for later building them into a JAR file. This [python script](http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html) might have been helpful but it extracts all `.java` classes from the source code.

Comment: I was under the impression that you could download source jars from the SDK configuration `android` tool to use in debugging - though I've never seen the need to try.

Comment: The SDK does contain jar files but it contains only stubs jar files. Once downloaded Android source code through SDK, it does not contain internal or hidden APIs.